# iphone code - how to create the update sign in the tab bar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

how can i create the update sign (the red one) in the tab bar ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do you mean `badgeValue` property of UIBarItem class?

Comment: badgeValue is a text to show near tabbar item. you can show some text, or just a number.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually a property of the UITabBarItem.